# Can not install Laravel cors in composer laravel or solution get api public with Laravel in ajx

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, web

I have jQuery ajax to call API in Laravel:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Menggunakan method GET untuk memanggil API
    console.log("asdasd");
    $.ajax({
        url: "PUBLIC API",
        method: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
        success: function(response) {
          console.log(response);
          // Lakukan sesuatu dengan response
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
          console.log("Terjadi kesalahan: " + error);
        }
      });
  });
```

but it can't be called because there is an error in the console that says

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'public' (redirected from 'public api') from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No' Access -Control-Allow-Origin' is on the requested resource.

How can I access this public API via Ajax jQuery in Laravel?

If the solution is that you have to download Laravel cors via composer, how do you do it because when I try it always fails?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS on your Laravel application by installing 'fruitcake/laravel-cors' package via Composer.

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors you can follow this documentation for configuration.